# Позиционирование объектов относительно другого объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, vector, 3d

ищу подсказку от более опытных коллег.

Мне необходимо понять формулу размещения объектов относительно, условно главного объекта, без использовать привязки к родителю в движке `Unity` (только с использованием векторов и кватернионов).

Привожу визуально наглядный пример того, чего я хочу добиться.

[image: изначальное положение объектов относительно главного]

При размещении главного объекта со смещенным поворотом, другие объекты должны размещаться относительно его позиции и поворота до.

[image: главный объект повернут, другие появляются в том же месте относительно главного объекта с учетом поворота]

Формулу изменения позиции я выявил, выглядит она так:

```
Vector3 newPosition = mainObject.position + (Quaternion.Euler(0, mainObject.eulerAngles.y, 0) * offset);
```

Где `offset` - это изначально зафиксированная относительная позиция между главным объектом и примыкающим.

Осталось выявить формулу для получения поворота примыкающего объекта, с этим у меня и возникли трудности.

Comment: [Transform.TransformPoint(Vector3)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) что бы узнать глобальную координату, локальной координаты в пространстве осей объекта.